# How to remove apostrophe's when writing to csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

i have been trying to add inputted data to a csv file and i have managed to get it 
and the output is:

```
'j')
return name, age, position, salary, years

outfile.write(str(add_emp())[1:-1] + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as a dirty solution you could just remove the apostrophes from the part you made string from them

```
outfile.write(str(add_emp())[1:-1] + '\n')
```

change to

```
outfile.write(str(add_emp()).replace("'", "")[1:-1] + '\n')
```

much more pythonic way would be to join them together

```
outfile.write(' '.join(add_emp() + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked